# Конвертация JSON в объект

Tags: java, json, jackson, конвертация

Столкнулся с проблемой конверации строки JSON в объект. Я использую

```
mapper.readValue(json, Block.getClass())
```

для парсинга. Проблема случаеться когда необходимо распарсить объект, который внутри себя содержит другой объект с конструктором.

### **Вот примеры классов:**

**Конвертируемый класс:**

```
  public class Block{

    private Staff staff;

    public Staff getStaff()
    {
        return staff;
    }

    public void setStaff(Staff staff)
    {
        this.staff = staff;
    }
}
```

**Класс с конструктором:**

```
public class Staff
{
    private String name;

    public Staff(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Как возможно конвертнуть его не прибегая к написанию собственного парессера?

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема? Вылетает исключение? Или просто не мапятся данные на вложенный объект? И не плохо было бы указать, какую библиотеку для маппинга Вы используете.

Comment: Я так понимаю используется Jackson. Попробуй создать пустой конструктор

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы десериализовать JSON не обязательно использовать класс из библиотеки, которую вы не можете изменить, чтобы добавить туда noarg-конструктор. Но вы можете создать наследуемый класс, в котором можно это сделать.

```
public class StaffJson extends Stuff
{
   public StaffJson() {
     super("");
   }
}
```

Или же просто создать другую модель и добавить туда конструктор. Потом можно написать метод, который будет конвертировать один объект в другой

```
 Staff convert(StaffJson sj) {
   return new Staff(sj.getName())
 }
```